# Get tag's references in AEM with Groovy console

Tags: java, groovy, aem

I am trying to get references/paths where some AEM tags are used.
I tried with this:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource
import com.day.cq.tagging.Tag
import com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver
import java.lang.Thread.*;
import javax.jcr.Node;

def tagpath = "/etc/tags";
def delay = 10 ; //in Milliseconds.

def query = getAllTags(tagpath)
def result = query.execute()

def rows = result.rows
def unusedTags = 0

rows.each { row ->
    Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource(row.path)
    if(res!=null){
        Tag tag = res.adaptTo(com.day.cq.tagging.Tag)
        Node tempNode = res.adaptTo(javax.jcr.Node);
        TagManager tm = resourceResolver.adaptTo(com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager);
        FindResults fr = tm.findByTitle(tag.title)
        RangeIterator rangeIterator = fr.resources; -> this throws Cast Exception
        //how to get paths of results (content) from fr to see where is this tag used

        Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(delay));
    }
}


def getAllTags(tagpath) {
 def queryManager = session.workspace.queryManager
 def statement = "/jcr:root"+tagpath+"//element(*, cq:Tag)"
 def query = queryManager.createQuery(statement, "xpath")
}
```

Now I am interested in how to get results from fr variable. Should I somehow adapt it to the Resource class or how can I get **path** to the assets/pages this returns?

FindResults findByTitle(String) - Searches for all content that is tagged with a tag that contains the given title as tag title.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource
import com.day.cq.tagging.Tag
import com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager
import com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager.FindResults
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver
import java.lang.Thread.*;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RangeIterator;


def tagpath = "/etc/tags";

def query = getAllTags(tagpath)
def result = query.execute()

def rows = result.rows
def counter = 1;

def tagTitles = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]

rows.each { row ->
Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource(row.path)
    if(res!=null){
        Tag tag = res.adaptTo(com.day.cq.tagging.Tag)
        Node tempNode = res.adaptTo(javax.jcr.Node);
        TagManager tm = resourceResolver.adaptTo(com.day.cq.tagging.TagManager);

        tagTitles.each { tagTitle ->
            if(tag.title.equalsIgnoreCase(tagTitle)){
                counter++;
                try{
                FindResults fr = tm.findByTitle(tag.title);
                Iterator rangeIterator = fr.resources;

                    if(rangeIterator.size() != 0){
                        println("Tag: " + tagTitle);
                        println("-- References: ");
                        println();

                        fr = tm.findByTitle(tag.title);
                        rangeIterator = fr.resources;
                        rangeIterator.each { resource -> 
                            println(resource.path);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                    println("REFERENCES NOT FOUND FOR: " + tagTitle);
                    }
                } catch(MissingMethodException ex){
                    println("Title not found in tag list: " + tagTitle);
                    println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
println("List lenght: " + tagTitles.size());
println("Number of tags with given title found: " + counter);

def getAllTags(tagpath) {
 def queryManager = session.workspace.queryManager
 def statement = "/jcr:root"+tagpath+"//element(*, cq:Tag)"
 def query = queryManager.createQuery(statement, "xpath")
}
```

This is the solution. Since Groovy doesn't work with RandeIterator, I started using its parent class Iterator.

------ EDIT ------

> I do not consider this as full answer since I don't know exact reason
>   for Groovy not to recognise this as a RangeIterator, so if someone can
>   answer that, please do.

Also, does this `fr = tm.findByTitle(tag.title);` get only references of tag with given title, or also references of his children?

Answer (score -1):

There is a Cast Exception as the class returned is not an Iterator. It is a [RangeIterator](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/RangeIterator.html) this class extends from iterator and provides some extra methods that can be useful.

It would be best if you use 
`RangeIterator rangeIterator = fr.resources`

Then you can normally inherit `hasNext next` methods

In this case this is RangeIterator of [Resource](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html) so you can obtain the path by calling the `getPath` method on each of the elements.

Comment: Groovy Console throws Cast exception on RangeIterator, but when I put an Iterator, it works.